# own Configurations Server build with Spring Boot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, properties, microservices

Does anyone of you now how I can build my own Configurations Server as a microservice to store and load `.properties` Files ?
I find the Spring Cloud Config really interesting but there you use git as the target and in my case it would be just a Filesystem ..
Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Cloud Config also supports native file system backend instead of git or svn. You can use it with the below options

```
spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations= xxxx
```

You can find more defailts in 'File System Backend' section of official doc : http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.3.0.RELEASE/

Comment: Thank you very much :) I will try it out